# Remove application from Google Launcher

Tags: google-launcher

How to remove link for an application in new Google Launcher?

[image]

Comment: What options are there when you right-click on the icon?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise Nothing special, just a typical browser right-click menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can see, you can't remove icons from the Google App Launcher. At best, you can move the apps you don't want to the bottom of the list.

From [Google Support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1714464?p=google_bar) under "Customize your menu":

> You can customize the launcher to show your favorite products at the top. To do this, drag and drop them within the menu.
>
> #### Add more products
>
> If you'd like to add one you don't see in the list:
>
> 1. Sign in to your [Google Account](https://accounts.google.com/).
> 2. Choose **App launcher** [image].
> 3. At the bottom of the menu, choose **More**.
> 4. Choose the Google products you want in your menu and drag to the top.

Obviously, you can move down as well as up, so that the apps you want are near the top.